# Google Sheet Converts Each Sheet to a PDF but doesn't carry over formatting. How could I make this work?

Tags: google-apps-script

We are trying to use the following code to convert individual sheets to individual PDFs and email the PDF to email addresses contained within:

```
   function myFunction(){

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID");
    var sheets = ss.getSheets();

    var B2Values = [];
    sheets.forEach(function(elt,index){
    //Get all  your email adresses
    B2Values.push(sheets[index].getRange(2,2).getValue());
    });

    //For each sheet in your Spreadsheet, it create a temporary Spreadsheet
 //who got only one sheet, with your sheet values, 
// transform it as pdf, send the pdf by email to your B2 email adress and delete
//the temporary Spreadsheet

    sheets.forEach(function(elt, index){
    var temporarySS = SpreadsheetApp.create("NAME_OF_THE_FILE_WHO_WILL_BE_SENT");
    var temporaryId = temporarySS.getId();
    var dataToMove = sheets[index].getRange(1,1,sheets[index].getLastRow(),sheets[index].getLastColumn()).getValues();
    var openingTemporarySS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(temporaryId);
      dataToMove.forEach(function(elt){
      openingTemporarySS.appendRow(elt);
      })
     MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: B2Values[index],
        subject: "YOUR_SUBJECT",
        attachments: [openingTemporarySS.getAs('application/pdf')]
    })

    DriveApp.getFileById(temporaryId).setTrashed(true);

    });
    }
```

It works great! But it does not keep merged cells and general formatting. Any thoughts or ideas on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You want to send each sheet in a Google Spreadsheet to each email which is retrieved from the cell "B2" as the PDF file.
- You want to keep the cell format of the sheet.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

#### Modification points:

- In your script, new Spreadsheet is created and only the values of data range are copied to it. By this, the cell format is not copied.
- In order to copy the values and format and create the sheet as PDF data, in your case, I think that `hideSheet()` can be used. For example, there are 2 sheets in a Spreadsheet, and when 1st tab is hidden by `hideSheet()` and the Spreadsheet is exported as the PDF data, only 2nd tab is exported as the PDF data. I think that this can be used for your situation. And also, this can also reduce the process cost.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("YOUR_SPREADSHEET_ID");
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();
  var B2Values = [];
  sheets.forEach(function(elt,index){
    //Get all  your email adresses
    B2Values.push(sheets[index].getRange(2,2).getValue());  // You can also use B2Values.push(elt.getRange(2,2).getValue());
  });

  // I modified below script.
  B2Values.forEach(function(e, i) {
    sheets.forEach(function(sheet, j) {if (i != j) sheet.hideSheet()});
    // SpreadsheetApp.flush(); // By the situation, this line might be required.
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: e,
      subject: "YOUR_SUBJECT",
      attachments: [ss.getBlob()]
    });
    sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {sheet.showSheet()});
  });
}
```

#### References:

- [hideSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#hidesheet)
- [showSheet()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#showsheet)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: @AndrewR Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.